# Color.HSVToColor gives different color values in each android devices

Tags: java, android, colors, androidx, hsv

This is very important. I didn't understand why this is happening.

> **I am simply converting one color to HSV color using wrapped Color class's method HSVToColor. And it gives me different colors on different devices. Anyone knows why it's happening and how to solve this?**

I have a simple scenario:-

**Example** ( I have check this scenario in two mobiles android 9 and android 6.0.1 )

```
int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{0.0f, 0.35564855f, 0.93725497f});
String hexString = Integer.toHexString(color);
```

it returns

> color :- -1074534 and hexString :- ffef9a9a
> **in android 9**

and

> color :- -1074791 and hexString :- ffef9999
> **in android 6.0.1**

any help will appreciate.

Comment: For future reference: You can undelete your [other post with the exact same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643787/color-hsvtocolor-gives-different-colors-in-different-device). No need to create a new post.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/graphics/Color.java#L378), `HSVToColor` calls a native method, so the difference is caused by the native code of the two devices. If you want the same result, you must use your own HSV to RGB algorithm.

Comment: They probably **fixed a bug** in how numbers are rounded in the calculations from HSV to RGB.